# Change font color of active dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am only a beginner in bootstrap and have a hard time figuring out how to change the css to my liking. I have a dropdown menu in my header and was able to change the colours. However, when the dropwdownmenu is selected, the font colour stays the same? How do I change this? I tried following:
`.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle {
        background:#ffffff !important; 
        color:#7dc623 !important;
    }`
but that doesn't change anything.

```html
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
        </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

See the background is green, but the text is black, but should be white.

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI2n1.png)

Comment: try to change it with the `color` CSS property ;)

Comment: @AndreiVoicu I did, but it doesn't change anything. I'll add a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing .open from the code did the trick:

```
.dropdown-toggle:active, .dropdown-toggle {
    background:#ffffff !important; 
    color:#7dc623 !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, it doesn't get effected by any JS code. Since in the code provided, I don't see the `open` class applied directly.

Comment: @ElysianStorm to be honest, I don't know. I am only a beginner at html and css, and learned bootstrap only this week. I am doing an assignment to finish a course and JS is not a part of it. How would I find out?

Answer (score 0):

Applying your CSS properties on directly on `a` tag may cause certain issues, it would be advisable to use a `span` between the `a` tag for your text.

ie:

```css
.navbar{
  background-color: #FFFF99 !important;
}

.text_in_span{
  color: #7dc623 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="text_in_span">Link 1</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="text_in_span">Link 2</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="text_in_span">Dropdown</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="text_in_span">Link 3</span></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="text_in_span">Link 4</span></a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I guess that should do the trick, cheers.

Comment: I have a hover effect on my links, so that wouldn't work. Removing the .open tag from my code worked :)

Comment: Well, it's always safe to place your text inside `span` when using `a' tags.

Comment: why is that? I've never used links with a span tag before.

Comment: Using a separate `span` tag removes the effects of other CSS or JS effects that are used on other parent tags, in this case `a` tag.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I'll try using it like that in the future, for the scope of my assignment however, I don't think it's necessary :)